# Excel - Return multiple matching values and sum it up in a single column

Tags: excel, indexing, sum, match

Requirement:

1 or more employees can be assigned to a single work and we need track the total working hours by summping up the time of all employees assigned to that work.

### WHat I have in my Excel

Sheet.1:.Assign.Work.(.Here.the.work.Id.will.be.assigned.to.each.resource.for.a.week)

A..........................|.B.........|.C.......|.D
Resource.Name...|.John......|.Mike....|.Sam
Week.Ending.......|.Work#.....|.Work#...|.Work#
08-Nov-2014........|.1.........|.2.......|.1
15-Nov-2014........|.1.........|.1.......|.2
22-Nov-2014........|.2.........|.1.......|.2
29-Nov-2014........|.2.........|.3.......|.3

Sheet.2:.Time.Tracker.(.here.the.working.hours.of.each.employee.is.tracked.minus.the.leaves.&.Holidays)

A..................|.B.........|.C.......|.D
Resource.Name......|.John......|.Mike....|.Sam
Week.Ending........|.Hours.....|.Hours...|.Hours
08-Nov-2014........|.40........|.35......|.40
15-Nov-2014........|.32........|.40......|.40
22-Nov-2014........|.40........|.35......|.32
29-Nov-2014........|.40........|.40......|.40

Sheet.3:.Time.against.each.work.is.tracked.on.a.weekly.basis

A..................|.B...........|.C........|.D
Work#..............|.1...........|.2........|.3
Work.Desc..........|.Web.Design..|.Hosting..|.Maintenace
08-Nov-2014........|.80..........|.35.......|.0            # Expected value
08-Nov-2014........|.40..........|.35.......|.0           # Actual value that I get using my formula

Now I have written a formula using index and match which does not work since I have the same work assigned to multiple ppl. It stops after the first match is found.

### FORMULA (Sheet 3, Cell B3)

=INDEX('Sheet2'!A1:D6,   #Gets the hours of the employee assigned to work id 1
MATCH('Sheet 3'!A4,'Sheet 2'!A1:D6,0),  #row num of 8th nov
MATCH(                  # Column no of the employee assigned work id #1
    INDEX('Sheet 1'!B1:D1,  1,  # Gets the resource name of work id #1
        MATCH('Sheet 3'!B1,'Sheet 1'!B3:D3,0)   # gets the row no for the matching work id
          ),
    'Sheet 2'!A1:D6,0))

Can some one help me with this problem.

Comment: Can you post your formula in the question?

Comment: =INDEX('Sheet2'!A1:D4,MATCH('Sheet 3'!A4,'Sheet 2'!A1:D4,0),MATCH(INDEX('Sheet 1'!B1:D1,1,MATCH('Sheet 3'!B1,'Sheet 1'!B3:D3,0)),'Sheet 2'!A1:D4,0))